# TimerService EJB does not get canceled if used with EJB Interceptor

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, interceptor, timertask

Hi every one i am having an issue with timer service, on timeout it perform some business logic if there is any exception in business logic. which is catched in one of interceptor as well as in timer service. then timer service is not canceled.  **timer.cancel();**

So how it works my timer service get exectued on timeout, it calls an ejb function, this ejb has an interceptor associated with it. if ejb function has any exception. Interceptor is basically logging that exception. then i have a code which stops the timer, it should work in case of success or failure, but it only stop timer in case of success. in case of failure(when exception occurs) it does not cancel the timer. so every time i restart jboss it try to excute the timer again (as it was failed).

***My Question is how can i stop timer in case of success and failure(exception). Please note i am using Interceptor as well (Which i can not remove, while removing it fixes the issue).***

Here is my different code classes which may help in understanding the issue.

**Business Logic Bean**

```
@Stateless
@Local(UtilityLocal.class)
@Interceptors({ ExceptionInterceptor.class })
public class UtilityEJB implements UtilityLocal {

public void doDomeThing(MazTimerTask task) {
    System.out.println("--- Business logic ---");
    Integer x = 5/0; // this will generate an exception
    System.out.println("--- Business logic ---");
}

}
```

**Interceptor**

```
public class ExceptionInterceptor {
 @Resource 
 private javax.ejb.SessionContext ctx;
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object aroundInvoke(final InvocationContext invocationContext)
        throws Exception { //NOPMD

        try {
            return invocationContext.proceed();
        } 
        catch (Exception exception) {
           System.out.println(" Logg the exception here");
           throw exception;
        }
    }
}
```

**Timer Service**

```
@Stateless
public class MazTimer implements MazTimerLocal, MazTimerRemote{
 @EJB
 private transient UtilityLocal ejb;
@Resource
private transient TimerService timerService;
@Timeout
@TransactionTimeout(3600)
public void handleTimeout(Timer timer) {
    MazTimerTask task = (MazTimerTask) timer.getInfo();

    if (task != null ) {
        try{
            ejb.doDomeThing(task);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("------------ Exception occured : " + task.getName());

        }
        finally {
            stopTimer(task);
        }
    }

}

public void startTimer(MazTimerTask task) {
    timerService.createTimer(new Date(), 10, task);
}
private void stopTimer(MazTimerTask task) {
    try {
        Timer timer = getTimer(task);

        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            System.out.println("------------ Timer stopped : " + task.getName());
        }

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {

    }
}
private Timer getTimer(Serializable timerId) {
    Timer timer = null;

    if (timerId != null) {
        Iterator<Timer> it = timerService.getTimers().iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Timer currentTimer = it.next();

            if (currentTimer.getInfo().equals(timerId)) {
                timer = currentTimer;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return timer;
}
}
```

Comment: So nobody ever had this issue, I am surprised please EXPERTS do help me